# Change bottom border of div based on the text content of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem I hope someone can help me with. I need to change the bottom border of a div based on the text contained in another div.

```
<ul id="featured_music">
<li style="width: 250px;">
    <div class="music_carousel_item_wrapper"> 
  <div class="music_carousel_item_content">
      <div class="music_carousel_item_image">
                    <div class="field field-name-field-live-show-preview field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><a href="http://xxxxx.com/"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://xxxxx.com/showpreviewtest4.png" width="250" height="187" alt=""></a></div></div></div>       </div>
    </div>
  <div class="music_carousel_item_hover" style="opacity: 0;">

                         <p>Drum and Bass</p> 
        <p><a href="http://xxxxx.com/showpreviewtest4.png" rel="lightbox" title="04.02.2014 - Transcendent Tuesdays"><i class="general foundicon-search"></i></a><a href="/show/drum-and-bass/04022014-transcendent-tuesdays"> <i class="general foundicon-paper-clip"></i></a></p>
                </div> 
</div>  
<div class="music_carousel_item_description">
<h3><a href="/show/drum-and-bass/04022014-transcendent-tuesdays">04.02.2014 - Transcendent Tuesdays</a></h3>
</div>  
</li>
```

This above markup is a carousel of items, for ease I have only included one item. For this code I want to change the bottom border of the "music_carousel_item_description" div to a specific colour depending on the value of the "music_carousel_item_hover"

For this particular example the text is "Drum and Bass" and the bottom border should be pink. If the text said "House", the bottom border should be blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the `music_carousel_item_hover` elements using [`$()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery).
2. Loop through them with [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each).
3. Check their content by using [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text).
4. Find the related `music_carousel_item_description` by using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to find the appropriate container (I think it might be an `li` in your case, can't tell for sure) then [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to find the `music_carousel_item_description`.
5. Finally, use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css) on that element to set its bottom border.

---

Rough example: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/bobuwazu/1)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="featured_music">
<li style="width: 250px;">
    <div class="music_carousel_item_wrapper"> 
  <div class="music_carousel_item_content">
      <div class="music_carousel_item_image">
                    <div class="field field-name-field-live-show-preview field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><a href="http://xxxxx.com/"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://xxxxx.com/showpreviewtest4.png" width="250" height="187" alt=""></a></div></div></div>       </div>
    </div>
  <div class="music_carousel_item_hover">

                         <p>Drum and Bass</p> 
        <p><a href="http://xxxxx.com/showpreviewtest4.png" rel="lightbox" title="04.02.2014 - Transcendent Tuesdays"><i class="general foundicon-search"></i></a><a href="/show/drum-and-bass/04022014-transcendent-tuesdays"> <i class="general foundicon-paper-clip"></i></a></p>
                </div> 
</div>  
<div class="music_carousel_item_description">
<h3><a href="/show/drum-and-bass/04022014-transcendent-tuesdays">04.02.2014 - Transcendent Tuesdays</a></h3>
</div>  
</li>
  </ul>
  <script>
    (function() {
      "use strict";

      // 1.Find the music_carousel_item_hover elements using $().
      // 2. Loop through them with each.
      $(".music_carousel_item_hover").each(function() {
        // Each DOM element in the loop is `this`, to get
        // a jQuery wrapper we use `$()` again
        // 3. Check their content by using text.
        var $el = $(this);
        var color;
        var content = $el.text().toLowerCase();
        if (content.indexOf("drum and bass") !== -1) {
          color = "blue";
        }
        else if (content.indexOf("house") !== -1) {
          color = "pink";
        }

        if (color) {
          // 4. Find the related music_carousel_item_description
          // by using closest to find the appropriate container
          // (I think it might be an li in your case, can't tell
          // for sure) then find to find the
          // music_carousel_item_description.
          // 5. Finally, use css on that element to set its bottom border.
          $el.closest('li')
            .find('.music_carousel_item_hover')
            .css("border-bottom", "1px solid " + color);
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would I be able to trouble you for a quick code example I can try. I am not well versed in JS or jQuery yet :(

Comment: I can send a link to the page if that helps at all. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @neo5287: Sure, I've added an example to the answer. But of course, you'll have to adjust it, etc., it's just a rough example.

Comment: Fricking awesome! You sir are a gentlemen! Answer accepted!